# FullText search MYSQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

so I am trying to make a simple search engine, that allows a user to search username, email, firstname and lastname.

However everytime I run the following it only returns russell.harrower instead of both russellharrower and russell.harrower

`SELECT *, MATCH(username) AGAINST ('russell') as score FROM`user_info`WHERE MATCH(username) AGAINST ('russell')`

I am not sure if i need to put a like status in there or what, so thought i would ask.

I want it to order the whole sql by the score.

Comment: Why not use `LIKE`? `SELECT * FROM user_info
WHERE username LIKE '%russel%';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using asterisk (wildcard) in boolean mode?

```
[...] AGAINST ('+russell*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1587371/Using-Fulltext-Indexes-in-MySQL---Part-2-Boolean-searches.htm

http://www.joedolson.com/boolean-query-in-mysql.php

/edit: don't use LIKE, especially with % in front of a phrase, it's veeery slow